# Error formatting disk; creating file system

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

EDIT: I WENT TO STORE AND EVERYTHING WAS OKAY, THANKS! :)

I'm trying to format using "disk" my new hard drive to install ubuntu fully on it, but the error comes up every time. I tried using fast and slow format, both don't seem to work. here is the full error I get:

> Error creating file system: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sda" mktable gpt' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sda
>    (udisks-error-quark, 0)

I'm trying to format because the installer also gets stuck, I dont know if the problem is my hard drive -it's new-, the pavilion computer or ubuntu. I doubt its the last one because I had similar problems installing windows 10

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is you disc ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix this. If it's a new drive, go to your dealer and request a sawp under warranty.  Be sure to mention "DOA" (Dead On Arrival)

To be absolutely sure:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl --scan
```

and then perform:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/XdY
```

where `X` and `Y` are the letters that came up for your drive in `sudo smartctl --scan`

*Sorry for the bad news.*

Comment: Can you explain why it's the drive? Like what is wrong with it?

Comment: As you said: " I had similar problems installing windows 10"

Comment: can anyone confirm? I want to know for sure before going back

Comment: **@Generalcooky:** see edited answer.  I agree with **A.B.** And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks, it's from a retail store so means they took it w/o any problem. Got a bigger one in return. Thanks for the help -

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

From a live Ubuntu disk try using the `dd` command to wipe the first bytes of the hard drive to erase the partition table it has now.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and type:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/XdY count=16`

where `X` and `Y` should be susbstituded for the drive you want. If it is the only drive on the computer then it is `sda`. Afterwards, either with `disks` or `gparted` make a new partition table on it.

Comment: I assume this also works if you use bootable usb?

Comment: yeah its the same thing

Comment: I'll try it, will this take a while?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to tell you. it only takes a second. stop the command in the teminal with ctrl + c

Comment: Okay, it didn't; comes up with this: "dd: writing to ‘/dev/sda’: Input/output error
33+0 records in
32+0 records out
16384 bytes (16 kB) copied, 3.73427 s, 4.4 kB/s"

Comment: That's not a good sign. Most probably its a hardware fault then. You will have to take it back.

Comment: Okay, that's enough I guess, I'm taking it back. I'll post if it goes alright

Comment: **Kiriazis:** Please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/645867/revisions)...  **;-)**

Comment: Oops! Sorry i just became a member yesterday so i'm still a noob at this.