# input/output error during write on /dev/sda

Tags: system-installation, grub-efi, error-handling

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my pc, the device currently does not have any OS. But I get the error "input/output error during write on /dev/sda"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error formatting disk; creating file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645820/error-formatting-disk-creating-file-system)